# How to get results from automated test on azuredevops

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I am stuck on trying to retrieve automated test results from build pipeline.
Is anyone here can help me to figure out please ?

This is my build pipeline : 
[image: Build pipeline]

I let the VSTEST as default :

```
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    runOnlyImpactedTests: false
    rerunFailedTests: false
```

Also the Publish Test Result is set as default :

```
steps:
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results **/TEST-*.xml'
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: VSTest
```

At the end I'm trying to post the test result on slack (but I don't know how to get the data that I need).

Following you can see the summary of the build :
[image]

And then the yaml of the POST SLACK NOTIFICATION :

```
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘date:yyyyMMdd’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘rev:.r’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972



steps:

- task: kasunkodagoda.slack-notification.slack-notification-task.SlackNotification@5

  displayName: 'Post Slack Notification'

  inputs:

    SlackApiToken: 'xoxp-I_HIDE_IT_BECAUSE_IT_IS_SECRET'

    Channel: '#devops_ci'

    Message: 'A new build is available $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)'

    UseVariableForMessage: true

    AuthorName: 'Continuous Integration'

    AuthorLink: 'https://I_HIDE_IT_BECAUSE_IT_IS_SECRET.visualstudio.com/SHIVA/_build?definitionId=1'

    PreText: 'Attachment Pre-Text'

    Text: 'Attachment Text'
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have a publish test results task? Please be more specific about what you are doing and the problem that exists (this is probably the one time a screenshot is OK unless you are using YAML builds)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I just add some informations, maybe you can give me some tips please. I've tryed to do it with publish test result but I can't

Comment: Thank you for adding that. Follow up question. Do the test results appear correctly on the build summary and just not slack, or are no results being collected? If its just the slack integration I'm not entirely sure if/how to get that to display the test result (ours just displays final build status)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thank you for your help, I have just updated the post with the screenshot of the summary and added yaml for post slack notification. The question is : how can I get the data from the previous task ? At the end I would like to post something like number_of_test_ok/number_of_total_tests on slack. I've just see you updated your comment : how can I display the final build status ?

Comment: I use the DevOps webhook to do the builds into slack, I haven't used the pipeline step. I'm not sure how to access the test count, I don't see a predefined variable for it so you may need a custom test runner task that outputs that information

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thank you very much. webhook is a part of the solution. i will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though [create a webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/slack?view=azure-devops) could help you post build status into slack, but its status message only for build instead on displaying its test task result.

As the content you described in comments, you want to post a message like number_of_test_ok/number_of_total_tests on slack. I'm afraid there hasn't such out-of-box feature can for you achieve this.

In addition, agree with @BradleyDotNET, there's no predefined variable store the message like the test count. Because getting these messages need to analyzed **attributes** from `.trx` file. This also is the compile logic which display test message in summary. See this: [Result mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#result-formats-mapping).

There has a such feature suggestion raised on our official forum: [Publish test results summary to slack channel](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/697015/publish-pipeline-test-results-summary-in-the-slack.html). You can vote and comment it there to make it has a broad community impact, also will improve the Azure Devops experience. Thus our product group will consider to take this feature into our develop roadmap.